# Getting error while retrieveing value from name

Tags: jquery

I am beginner with jquery, I am getting error while getting input from name in jquery..
My code is...
HTML

```
<input type="text" name="pcpfname" id="pcpfname" class="text" />
<input type="submit" name="pcpsubmit" id="pcpsubmit" value="Submit" />
```

Jquery

```
$('#pcpsubmit').click(function(){
var pcpfname = $('input[name=pcpfname]');
alert (pcpfname);
});
```

My alert message is

```
[object Object]
```

Comment: next time instead of an alert, try 'console.log', you will be able to naviguate inside an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **val()** to get value

```
$('#pcpsubmit').click(function(){
var pcpfname = $('input[name="pcpfname"]');
alert (pcpfname.val());
});
```

and you should use **" quotes** to selecting name attr in latest versions

Comment: @JohnjohnGa: Have a look at here http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ ..you can read this line **An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory.**

Comment: I don't care about this line, it is not mandatory - it is recommended - Maybe They plan to remove this in the futur

Answer (score 1):

You have to call [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on your input field.

```
$('#pcpsubmit').click(function(){
var pcpfname = $('input[name="pcpfname"]').val();
alert (pcpfname);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var pcpfname = $('input[name="pcpfname"]').val();
```